# cache speed related issue

Tags: c, optimization, caching

just wondering if I have a matrix like this:

[image]

so for the entry in the red position, I just want to know if the green entry is 1 or 0. If it is 0, I just have the value 0 in the same red position of a new matrix. So
if the current position of the red entry is at Matrix[4,3], then the input to the position Matrix[4,3] will be 1 since the green entry (the top-left entry of red) is 1. If the green entry is 0, then Matrix[4,3] will be 0.

So I have to do it pretty much for every entry in this matrix (except the entries that don't have the top-left neighbour for example all entries in first column would not have the top-left neighbour so this don't have to be done for those). I am just wondering will it makes a difference in terms of speed (cache access,reading, writing...etc) if I do the following in C (note that C is row-major):

```
Code 1:
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
        row = j - 1;
        col = i - 1; // oldMatrix here is the matrix in the attached image here
    *** newMatrix[j][i] += oldMatrix[row][col]; // new Matrix is the matrix to put the //left-top corner value
        }
    }
    }


Code 2:
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
        row = j - 1;
        col = i - 1; // oldMatrix here is the matrix in the attached image here
        if(oldMatrix[row][col] == 1) {
         newMatrix[j][i] = 1;
        } else {newMatrix[j][i] = 0};
        }
    }
    }
```

is it better to have this:

```
*** newMatrix[j][i] += oldMatrix[row][col]
```

or have this instead:

```
        if(oldMatrix[row][col] == 1) {
         newMatrix[j][i] = 1;
        } else {newMatrix[j][i] = 0};
```

So the first one (the line with ***) will first have to read the value of oldMatrix[row][col] and then write to newMatrix[j][i] no matters what.

But the second code will read oldMatrix[row][col] during the "if" check. Then we just assign (assign means "write" 1 or 0 to the newMatrix[j][i] without having to copy oldMatrix[row][col] to the newMatrix[j][i]).

So which one will be better in terms of speed if we talking about cache performance (C is row-major) and why the option would be faster or better?

thank you

Comment: Why would you need an `if` if you're doing a direct assignment with no alteration?

Comment: If you want this to be fast, you should use `memcpy` to copy entire rows from the input array to the output array.

Comment: @tadman the if is to check what value the top left corner is, if it is 0, then I assign 0, if it is 1 then I assign 1. This if has to do with the second code, not the first code. The first code I just don't care the value in the top left corner and just put it inside the new matrix. The second code, I didn't copy the top left corner value into matrix, I assign 1 or 0 depending on what the value in top left corner neighbour is.

Comment: If the initial contents of `newMatrix` are known or intended to be (e.g.) all-zero, and it has the same dimensions and element type as `oldMatrix`, then you could make *all* the copies with a single `memcpy()`, followed by fixing up the first element of each row other than the first.

Comment: @hodondo, you seem to be missing tadman's point, which is that if all the elements of oldMatrix are either 0 or 1, then your `if` / `else` alternative is equivalent to simply `newMatrix[j][i] = oldMatrix[row][col]`.

Comment: Also, from a cache usage perspective, if you continue with an element by element approach instead of a bulk approach with `memcpy()`, then your biggest win would probably come from flipping the fast and slow moving indices.  Because, as you say, C uses row-major order, you want the fast moving index to be the one that traverses elements in the same row.  That's the *second*, not the first.

Comment: Can you just use bits; like maybe `newBitMatrix[row+1] = (oldBitMatrix[row] & 0x80) | (oldBitMatrix[row]  >> 1);`?

Comment: Note the way `newMatrix` and `oldMatrix` array are created/allocated is missing while this is quite critical for performance. If this is a 2D array statically allocated, then it is flatten and fast. If you created it by allocating array of pointers pointing on dynamically allocated arrays (ie. jagged arrays), then this is not efficient for the cache. This is not as critical as swapping the i-j loops so for access to be more contiguous, nor the horrible `if` preventing the compiler to generate any fast code.